# Trying to get image URL from meta data of custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WordPress site that has custom posts and I am trying to output the metadata in a feed. The feed will be a json object but the problem that i am having is that for one of the fields for an image url has the value "field_53ecfb598628f". I have no idea what this is or how to get to the url for the image.

To get the value i am using the following code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, '_photos_0_photo');
if( !empty($terms) )
{
    $term = array_pop($terms);

    $custom_field = get_field('_photos_0_photo', $term );

    $test = $custom_field;

}
```

and $test would be set to "field_53ecfb598628f". How do I find my URL from this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure by this structure you are using Advanced Custom Fields for this custom meta fields. Therefor you should not use get_field("_photos_0_photo") but guessing by the field name get_field("photos").

By the name I'm guessing its the gallery or repeater field, so you should probably loop trough that, because it will return an array.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/